# Service com.apple.quickook doesn't stop from restarting

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite, launchd, spotlight, daemon

Running Mac OS X 10.2.2 in MacBookPro model `MacBookPro11,2`.

I'm having this issue that I could find using `console` application:

A daemon named `com.apple.quicklook` deosn't stop from restarting after `0` second of activity.
Here, one of the many failed start from `com.apple.quicklook`. It's always the same issue.

[image]

After a reboot, I tried manipulate the daemon with `launchctl`, to stop it, reload it, etc. without be able to catch the process before it's death.

More than not be able to see preview of applications or pictures in my `Finder`. This one freeze constantly and `Spotlight` too.

Comment: btw, I'm assuming 10.2.2 is a typo for 10.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a symbolic link `/tmp` points to `/var/tmp`.

Guess it's some duck tape, though ... Someone could explain me why this issue appeared and how and if it's a better solution?

Comment: mine works fine with <string>/tmp</string>

Comment: don't know what causes the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 3rd party qlgenerator files & see if that helps.

`/Library/QuickLook` or `~/Library/QuickLook` is most likely.

Drag them all out & reboot.

(`/System/Library/QuickLook` ought to be Apple qlgenerators, so I'd leave that alone for now.)

If you're fixed, eliminate by halves - drop half of them back in, reboot again - if it's still OK, then the suspect is in the other half.
Keep halving til you find the one.

Comment: It  appears to be fixed, (see my own response). By the Way, what was your guess concerning qlgenerators?

Comment: I had a few qlgenerators go bad with Yosemite - that was the way I figured out which needed updates